# Why event is not tiggered，when it is raised in a event handle sub？

Tags: vb.net, events

I want use a Nuget package named BeetleX in .net core VB.

bellow is a sample code:

```vb
Imports BeetleX
Imports BeetleX.EventArgs
Imports System

Namespace ConsoleApp4
    Class Program
        Inherits ServerHandlerBase

        Private Shared server As IServer

        Public Shared Sub Main(ByVal args As String())
            server = SocketFactory.CreateTcpServer(Of Program)()
            server.Open()
            Console.Write(server)
            Console.Read()
        End Sub

        Public Overrides Sub SessionReceive(ByVal server As IServer, ByVal e As SessionReceiveEventArgs)
            Dim name As String = e.Stream.ToPipeStream().ReadLine()
            Console.WriteLine(name)
            e.Session.Stream.ToPipeStream().WriteLine("hello " & name)
            e.Session.Stream.Flush()
            MyBase.SessionReceive(server, e)
        End Sub
    End Class
End Namespace
```

I don't like this mode, whole program is a Class(object) inherited from a dedicated fucntion Class. and the events handle class's handler is input to a object(parameter of create object), the object directly use these events handle sub internally.

I would like used normal mode, program get the events from the object, program can handle the events it self, and can get informations from the object.
below is normal way in vb.net

```vb
Dim WithEvents EClass As New EventClass
' Call the method that raises the object's events.
Sub TestEvents()
    EClass.RaiseEvents()
End Sub

' Declare an event handler that handles multiple events.
Sub EClass_EventHandler() Handles EClass.XEvent, EClass.YEvent
    MsgBox("Received Event.")
End Sub

Class EventClass
    Public Event XEvent()
    Public Event YEvent()
    ' RaiseEvents raises both events.
    Sub RaiseEvents()
        RaiseEvent XEvent()
        RaiseEvent YEvent()
    End Sub
End Class
```

So I changed code, to raise a event in event handle sub and public the event.
but why the event can not be triggered?

```vb
Imports System
Imports BeetleX
Imports BeetleX.EventArgs

Class Program

    Dim WithEvents myevent As MyServerHandler

    Private Shared server As IServer
    Shared a As String
    Public Shared Sub Main(args As String())
        Console.WriteLine("Hello World!")
        server = SocketFactory.CreateTcpServer(Of MyServerHandler)()
        server.Open()
        Console.Write(server)
        Console.Read()

    End Sub

    Public Sub SessionReceive(ByVal server As IServer, ByVal e As SessionReceiveEventArgs) Handles myevent.XSessionReceive
        Dim name As String = e.Stream.ToPipeStream().ReadLine()
        Console.WriteLine(name)
        e.Session.Stream.ToPipeStream().WriteLine("hello " & name)
        e.Session.Stream.Flush()
        'MyBase.SessionReceive(server, e)

    End Sub

    Public Class MyServerHandler
        Inherits ServerHandlerBase
        Public Event XSessionReceive(ByVal server As IServer, ByVal e As SessionReceiveEventArgs)
        Public Overrides Sub SessionReceive(ByVal server As IServer, ByVal e As SessionReceiveEventArgs)
            'Dim name As String = e.Stream.ToPipeStream().ReadLine()
            'Console.WriteLine(name)
            'e.Session.Stream.ToPipeStream().WriteLine("hello " & name)
            'e.Session.Stream.Flush()

            MyBase.SessionReceive(server, e)
            RaiseEvent XSessionReceive(server, e)
        End Sub

    End Class


End Class
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go! See comments in the code.

```
Class Program

    Private Shared WithEvents myhandler As MyServerHandler

    Private Shared WithEvents server As IServer

    Shared a As String
    Public Shared Sub Main(args As String())
        Console.WriteLine("Hello World!")
        server = SocketFactory.CreateTcpServer(Of MyServerHandler)()
        ' Get reference to MyServerHandler instantiated by CreateTcpServer().
        myhandler = server.Handler
        server.Open()
        Console.Write(DirectCast(server, IServer))
        Console.Read()

    End Sub

    ' Handles XSessionReceive event from MyServerHandler created by CreateTcpServer().
    Public Shared Sub SessionReceive(ByVal server As IServer, ByVal e As SessionReceiveEventArgs) Handles myhandler.XSessionReceive
        Dim name As String = e.Stream.ToPipeStream().ReadLine()
        Console.WriteLine(name)
        e.Session.Stream.ToPipeStream().WriteLine("hello " & name)
        e.Session.Stream.Flush()
    End Sub

    Public Class MyServerHandler
        Inherits ServerHandlerBase

        Public Event XSessionReceive(ByVal server As IServer, ByVal e As SessionReceiveEventArgs)

        Public Overrides Sub SessionReceive(ByVal server As IServer, ByVal e As SessionReceiveEventArgs)
            MyBase.SessionReceive(server, e)
            RaiseEvent XSessionReceive(server, e)
        End Sub

    End Class

End Class
```